# Sum of Banach spaces norm

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $ \left ( X_{1},\left \|  \right \|_{1} \right ) $,$ \left ( X_{2},\left \|  \right \|_{2} \right ) $ two Banach spaces in the vector space X.

How to prove that $\left \| x \right \|= \inf \left \{\left \| x_{1} \right \|_{1}+\left \| x_{2} \right \|_{2}:x=x_{1}+x_{2} \ , \ x_{1}\in X_{1} \ \ x_{2}\in X_{2} \right \} $ defines a norm in $ X_{1}+X_{2} $

My attempt :
$ \left \| x \right \|=0 \Leftrightarrow \exists \left ( x_{n} \right )_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset X_{1} \ ,  \exists \left ( y_{n} \right )_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset X_{2}: x=x_{n}+y_{n} \ and \ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left \| x_{n} \right \|_{1}=0 \ $ and $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left \| y_{n} \right \|_{2}=0 $
 I can't prove that $x=0$

Comment: Your question is how to prove that $x\mapsto \|x\|$ it’s a norm. A good answer then could be: show that it satisfies the axioms of a norm. If you tell us what have you tried and which of the axioms you’re not able to prove, you might get a better answer.

Comment: I proved the homogeneity axiom and the norm of the zero vector equals zero, but I can't prove that if the norm of a vector x is zero then x is the zero vector

Comment: There’s also something here that’s not quite clear to me. Are you regarding $X_1$ and $X_2$ as subspaces of $X$?

Comment: yes but $X$ is not equiped with a norm

Comment: I forgot to add that $X_{1}$and$X_{2}$ are Banach spaces

Comment: So if $X$ is a Banach space, then $X$ must have a norm, right?

Comment: You have $\lim_{n}\|x_n\|=\lim_n\|y_n\| = 0$ it follows that $x = \lim_{n}x_n+y_n = 0$.

Comment: Sorry $X$ is not banach space

Comment: well I don't know about completeness, but this is indeed a norm.

Comment: So give us a proof please

Comment: Your norm is not positive definite in general. One natural assumption which ensures this (actually, it is equivalent) is that $X_i \hookrightarrow Y$ (continuous embedding) for $i = 1,2$ and some Hausdorff topological vector space $Y$. If you are interested, I can post a proof for this.

Comment: I got it, thank you. Is there an example where the norm is not positive definite?

Comment: Do you have a reference to this result?

Answer (score 0):

Picking up from where you left off, if $\|x_n\|_1\to 0$, then
$$
\|x_n-x_m\|_1\le \|x_n\|_1+\|x_m\|_1 \to 0$$
when $n,m\to\infty$. Thus, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy in $X_1$, and thus converges to a point, say $z$. The functions $v\mapsto \|v\|_1$ is continuous, so $\|z\|_1=\lim_n \|x_n\|=0$. Thus $z=0$.

By the same reasoning, $y_n\to 0$ in $X_2$.

Finally,

$$
x=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n+y_n=0
$$
as desired.

Comment: $$
x=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n+y_n=0
$$  $x_n+y_n$ is an element of $X$ wich is not a topological space , so you can't have $lim_{n\to\infty} x_n+y_n$

Comment: @Student you’re right, it is more subtle than I anticipated, I was under the impression that the ambient space was a topological vector space. Sorry about that. I’ll think about it a bit more